# If statement ignores return method, other solutions?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, 2d-games

I have a class called Cells and in it I have an update method that runs this piece of code:

```
if(goalReached){
  if(returnNearestCell() > -1 && isTarget && this.checkCollide(cells.get(returnNearestCell()).x, cells.get(returnNearestCell()).y, cells.get(returnNearestCell()).mass)){
    addMass(cells.get(returnNearestCell()).mass);
    cells.get(returnNearestCell()).mass = 20;
    cells.get(returnNearestCell()).x = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);
    cells.get(returnNearestCell()).y = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 701);
    isTarget = false;
  }
  if(returnNearestCell() > -1 && !isTarget){
    goalX = cells.get(returnNearestCell()).x; 
    goalY = cells.get(returnNearestCell()).y; 
    target = cells.indexOf(returnNearestCell());
    isTarget = true;

  }else if(returnNearestCell() == -1 ){ 
    goalX = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);
    goalY = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 701);
    isTarget = false;
  }
  if(!isTarget){
    addMass(5);
  }
  goalReached = false;
}
```

Basically to sum it up, each cell looks for the nearest cell with a smaller mass and if a cell is found then set the goalX and goalY to the position of that cell. If no such cell with the same criteria is found then just go to a random position. The code works fine until for some reason the first if statement gets ignored:

```
returnNearestCell() > -1
```

Then I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

My returnNearestCell method goes as follows:

```
public int returnNearestCell(){

int x = 0;
int distance = 9999999;
int min = distance;

for(Cell cell : cells){
  if(this != cell){
    distance = (int)Math.sqrt((this.x - cell.x)*(this.x - cell.x ) + (cell.y - this.y)*(cell.y  - this.y));
    if(distance < min && this.mass > cell.mass + 10){
      min = distance;
      x = cells.indexOf(cell);
    }else if(distance < min && this.mass < cell.mass + 10 && cell.cellCount == cells.size()){
      x = -1;
    }
  }
}

return x;
}
```

This method returns the index of the cell with the criteria or -1. My question is: Is there any way to avoid this OutofBoundsException? I've tried multiple methods like doing a double check but I still get the same issue.

Comment: I suggest you do appropriate diagnostic work so you can narrow this down into a [mcve]. Given that there's behaviour you don't understand (the supposed "ignoring" of the `if` statement) I would try to work that out first.

Comment: I'd also suggest calling `returnNearestCell` *once* in your method, and using that result throughout your method. Why would you want to call it that many times? I'd probably actually make it return the `Cell` (or null if nothing is found) rather than the index, too... it'll make your code a lot simpler, I suspect...

Comment: It can help to know at what line it is throwing the exception

Comment: The exception is always thrown here: cells.get(returnNearestCell()).y = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 701);

Comment: Is there any way to store an object into a variable and access it through that variable?

Comment: You are *mutating the cell* and then call `getNearestCell()` again, expecting the result to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cells.get(returnNearestCell()).mass = 20;
cells.get(returnNearestCell()).x = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);
cells.get(returnNearestCell()).y = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 701);
```

Here, you are mutating the cell and then call `returnNearestCell()` again. Since that method now runs with the changed parameters, the return value is possibly different. Most importantly, you shift the cell along the `x` coordinate and it is then in a different position when evaluated by the next call to `returnNearestCell()`.

You might want to look up *non-atomic updates* and *concurrent modification* for more on this topic.

> Is there any way to store an object into a variable and access it through that variable?

Yes and it's the solution to your problem:

```
if (goalReached) {
   // retrieve nearest cell once before modification
   final int nearestCellIndex = returnNearestCell();
   if (nearestCellIndex > -1 && isTarget) {
       // save cell.
       final Cell nearestCell = cells.get(nearestCellIndex);

       if (this.checkCollide(nearestCell.x, nearestCell.y, nearestCell.mass)) {

            // remainder of your code
       }
   }
}
```

Note that it is probably preferable to have `returnNearestCell()` return `Optional<Cell>` or at least a `Cell` object directly. Same goes for `checkCollide()` which could simply take a `Cell` object as parameter.

Comment: What would my method return if no cell is found(if I return the cell directly)?

Comment: @BruceTheGoose If the return type is `Cell`, your only sane option is to return `null`. If using Java 8, you might want to consider using [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) and return `Optional.empty()`.